# INCLUDEs are not copied during program COPY

Tags: copy, include, abap, modularization

I copy a program SAPBC414T_BOOKINGS_01 to new name ZSAPMZ_BOOKINGS_01 in a new package ZBC400_01.

I select all items including INCLUDEs. SAP asks me to rename the includes and I rename them as shown here:

[image]

However, after copying I open my program `ZSAPMZ_BOOKINGS_01` in my package `ZBC400_01` and I am surprised to see all INCLUDEs have the same names as in source program. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entering a new name in the popup with includes is not enough, you also need to select all the lines of the includes you want to copy before you click the Copy button.